# Chosen jquery plugin not updating with <optgroup>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

strange situation happening here. I'm using the jquery plugin chosen.js. I'm updating a dropdown that is already on the page with an ajax call and jquery.  here is a little bit of the sample code.
here is my dropdown as shown in the page.

```
<div id="singleDropDownBlock" style="display: none">

    <select id="SingleDropDown"  class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Choose your start Location" onchange="GetFromNodeValue();">
        <!--<option>select a strating locnation based on category.</option>-->

    </select>

</div>
```

This is the code loading the values into the dropdown using jquery.

```
     function GetResultsFromMultiCategory(data)
     {


             for (i = 0; i < data.d.categories.length; i++)
             {
                 //console.log(data.d.categories[i].catNode);

                 if (data.d.categories[i].catNode == "0")
                 {

                     $('#SingleDropDown').append("<optgroup " + "label= " + '"' + data.d.categories[i].catName + '"' + ">");
                     console.log("<optgroup " + "label= " + '"' + data.d.categories[i].catName + '"' + ">");
                     //onOrOff = false;  </optgroup>
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     $('#SingleDropDown').append("<option " + "value=" + data.d.categories[i].catNode+ ">" + data.d.categories[i].catLoc + "</option>");
                     console.log("<option " + "value='" + data.d.categories[i].catNode + "'>" + data.d.categories[i].catLoc + "</option>");

                     if (typeof(data.d.categories[i + 1]) != "undefined")
                     {

                         if (data.d.categories[i + 1].catNode == "0")
                         {
                             $('#SingleDropDown').append("</optgroup>");
                             console.log("</optgroup>");

                         }//end second if
                     }//end first if
                 }//end else

             }

             $('#SingleDropDown').append("</optgroup>");
             console.log("</optgroup>");
             $("#SingleDropDown").chosen({ placeholder_text_single: "Choose Map" });
             $("#SingleDropDown").trigger("chosen:updated");
      }
```

for some reason chosen does not update with the  it only updates with the . Is there anything I'm missing?  can someone please point me in the right direction. 
I also can't get chosen to update the placeholder. All i get is the first item in list as the display.

thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: does anyone has the slighest of clues how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out my issue. I'll post the answer here so that it may help someone else someday.

The problem here is that appending one select at a time was being closed by the browser. Therefore here is the best way to do this.

```
function GetResultsFromMultiCategory(data)
         {
             $("#singleDropDownBlock").show();

             $('#SingleDropDown').append("<option></option>");

             var myOptions = '';
             for (i = 0; i < data.d.categories.length; i++)
             {    
                 if (data.d.categories[i].catNode == "0")
                 {
                     myOptions += "<optgroup " + "label= " + '"' + data.d.categories[i].catName + '"' + ">";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     myOptions += "<option " + "value=" + data.d.categories[i].catNode + ">" + data.d.categories[i].catLoc + "</option>";

                     if (typeof(data.d.categories[i + 1]) != "undefined")
                     {
                         if (data.d.categories[i + 1].catNode == "0")
                         {
                             myOptions += "</optgroup>";
                         }
                     }
                 }    
             }
             myOptions += "</optgroup>";
             $('#SingleDropDown').append(myOptions);
             $("#SingleDropDown").chosen({placeholder_text_single: "Choose Start Location" });
         }
```

the take away here is that when using append instead of appending each line, build the string and then append it to the html element.